# ¡Como hacer una subconsulta en SQL?

Tags: mysql

Como hago para que estas consultas estén todas en una misma?

```
SELECT FECHA_PROMESA AS PD, SUM(CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE) AS C_P FROM pedidos WHERE EMPRESA = 'SOLMAQ' AND FECHA_PROMESA >= '2021-06-01' AND FECHA_PROMESA <= '2021-10-05'
SELECT FECHA_PROMESA AS TW, SUM(CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE) AS C_P FROM pedidos WHERE EMPRESA = 'SOLMAQ' AND FECHA_PROMESA >= '2021-10-06' AND FECHA_PROMESA <= '2021-10-08'
SELECT FECHA_PROMESA AS NW, SUM(CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE) AS C_P FROM pedidos WHERE EMPRESA = 'SOLMAQ' AND FECHA_PROMESA >= '2021-10-09' AND FECHA_PROMESA <= '2021-10-15'
```

y quiero que en el resultado me aparezcan los 3 resultados en uno.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si mal no entiendo lo que necesitas usar es **UNION ALL** para agrupar las subconsultas en una sola.

```
SELECT FECHA_PROMESA AS PD, SUM(CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE) AS C_P FROM pedidos WHERE EMPRESA = 'SOLMAQ' AND FECHA_PROMESA >= '2021-06-01' AND FECHA_PROMESA <= '2021-10-05'
UNION ALL
SELECT FECHA_PROMESA AS TW, SUM(CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE) AS C_P FROM pedidos WHERE EMPRESA = 'SOLMAQ' AND FECHA_PROMESA >= '2021-10-06' AND FECHA_PROMESA <= '2021-10-08'
UNION ALL
SELECT FECHA_PROMESA AS NW, SUM(CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE) AS C_P FROM pedidos WHERE EMPRESA = 'SOLMAQ' AND FECHA_PROMESA >= '2021-10-09' AND FECHA_PROMESA <= '2021-10-15'
```

Comment: Esto era lo que buscaba

Comment: Ok, sigue adelante amigo!

Answer (score 1):

Si mal no veo, todas seleccionan lo mismo, pero mi duda es por que haces 3 rangos de fechas colectivos, si son todas secuenciales ???
Es decir, estás haciendo una seleccion entre el '2021-06-01' y '2021-10-15', por que no pedir todo de una mejor ??

```
SELECT 
    FECHA_PROMESA AS FP, 
    SUM(CANTIDAD_PENDIENTE) AS CP
FROM pedidos
WHERE EMPRESA = 'SOLMAQ'
AND FECHA_PROMESA BETWEEN '2021-06-01' AND '2021-10-15'
```

Comment: esta bien.. pero no tan bien.. revisemos si OP no necesita los tramos por separado ;)

Comment: Eso fue lo que consulte, por que de todos modos, puede subdividir esos datos luego de haber hecho la consulta.

Comment: pero no veo un comentario que pregunte eso!!!

Comment: Hay que esperar a que el OP responda a las preguntas que se le hacen

Comment: las dudas sobre su pregunta, van en los comentarios.. por eso ;)

Comment: Como sea, aun no responde, hay que esperar a que responda.

Comment: La idea por la cual estoy seccionando las fechas, es porque en cada una de ellas debo extraer las cantidades pendientes, y como lo estoy convirtiendo a graficas utilizando procedimientos con PROCEDURE.

Comment: Por lo tanto para hacer la grafica, ya solo obtengo las cantidades

Comment: Podrías agregar eso al codigo para ver como lo estas haciendo